# Guess What Am I...?

Tags: riddle

> What am I:
>
> The person who creates me does not use me.
>
> The person who buys me does not use me.
>
> The person who uses me does not see me.

Comment: Hei.. we have 2 Sid here.

Comment: Quite sure this is a duplicate. It's a pretty classic riddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are

> a Coffin

The person who creates me does not use me.

> The creator do not want to die.

The person who buys me does not use me.

> He but it for someone else

The person who uses me does not see me.

> Because he is already died.

Comment: Salute to you sir...